# CSS Promo Box Center Positioning

Tags: css

I have a set of 3 promo-boxes

```
.promo-boxes .promo-box {
    width: 49.5% !important;
    margin-right: 0.3% !important;
    margin-top: 1% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    float: none !important;
}

.promo-boxes .promo-box.second,
.promo-boxes .promo-box.last {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

So as you can see I've tried using position and float as well as other text-left etc to no success.

I want these to be centered anything i'm missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this using flexbox.

```css
.promo-boxes {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color:white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.spacebetween {
 justify-content: space-between;

}
.promo-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-boxes">
  <div class="promo-box">
  promo box
  </div>
  <div class="promo-box">
  promo box
  </div>
  <div class="promo-box">
  promo box
  </div>
</div>

<div class="promo-boxes spacebetween">
  <div class="promo-box">
  promo box
  </div>
  <div class="promo-box">
  promo box
  </div>
  <div class="promo-box">
  promo box
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.promo-boxes .promo-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

You may need to define a width, unless you want it to be as big as its content. Also, don't use `!important` unless you have no other choice, whatsoever!